# check content type in http request using CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

I dont know how to extract the "Content-type" header from de request

```
server = http.createServer (req, res) -> 
  #TODO req.headers.?
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just `req.headers['content-type']`. It can be `undefined` though so be careful.